# What is the cheapest way to travel from North to South island in New Zealand?

Tags: budget, ferries, new-zealand, fares

After some search I found the [following fare](https://www.interislander.co.nz/) for sail crossing:

- Wellington to Picton Thursday, 22nd January 2015 - **2 Adults**
- Picton to Wellington Sunday, 8th February 2015 - **2 Adults**

### With a van

- NZ$273 each way → NZ$550 roundtrip for 2
- add NZ$50/trip/2 pers. for flexibility → NZ$650

### Without a vehicule

- NZ$130 each way → NZ$260 roundtrip for 2
- add NZ$20/trip for flexibility → NZ$300

### Question

Do you know a cheaper way to cross ? (flight maybe?)

Date are flexible as we travel from mid-january to mid-february same for from/to destination.

Comment: [Kayak](http://kayak.com) is showing flights from Wellington to Christchurch as low as NZ$98 per person round trip.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what your vehicle is, but most rental agencies charge hefty surcharges if you return it on a different island.

Comment: Midnight and 4 AM sailings are generally cheaper too.  Sometimes the 6:30 sailing may be acceptable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The overall cost really depends on whether you want to bring a vehicle or not. It is much more expensive to bring a vehicle.

If you want to bring a vehicle, then your only reasonable option is the ferry. There are two ferry services:

- [Interislander](https://www.interislander.co.nz/)
- [Bluebridge](http://www.bluebridge.co.nz/)

If you do not want to bring a vehicle, the cheapest way is probably to fly (although the ferry has better scenic views, unless the ocean conditions are rough). Flights between the main centres (Auckland, Wellington, Christchurch) will be the cheapest. Check:

- [Grabaseat](http://grabaseat.co.nz) which is Air New Zealand's discount fare outlet
- [Jetstar](http://jetstar.co.nz)

If you are renting a vehicle, then ask the rental company about options they have for ferry travel. Almost all rental companies will let you drop off the vehicle on one side of the Strait, travel by ferry without a vehicle, then pick up an equivalent one on the other side.

Comment: +1 Definitely cheaper to not take a car. Good advice about dropping off and picking up a car on either side. Also, for flights, sounds air does flights between Wellington and Blenheim/Picton for $99 pp one way and Nelson for $120 pp one way.